# Perl - create and automate a hash table with arrays as the values

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap, hashtable, key-value

im trying to achieve the following:

I have a txt file with a random list of files,
I want to sort the files by their path.

for eample:
The list is:

```
c:\foo\bar\bbb.txt
c:\foo\bar\ccc.txt
d:\xxx\eee.txt
c:\foo\bar\aaa.txt
d:\xxx\ddd.txt
```

i want the data like this:

```
[KEY]
c:\foo\bar
[Values]
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt

[KEY]
d:\xxx\
[Values]
ddd.txt
eee.txt
```

i thought of using a hash map, with arrays as the values.
i couldnt figure out the currect syntax.

this is some of my code:

```
open (FILELIST, "$file") or ...;
my @filelist = <FILELIST>;
my %uniqueFolders;
    foreach $fileList_line (@filelist)
      {
         my $file = (File::Spec::Win32->splitpath($fileList_file))[1];
           if ( !$file ~~ @temp = keys %uniqueFolders)
             {
                 %uniqueFolders{$file} = ????????????

              }
```

how do i access the array to add/read from it?

and how can i automate it so the arrays are created when needed..

Help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going off down a blind alley. You don't need to create arrays, as perl has a feature called [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/autovivification-0.16/lib/autovivification.pm).

By writing to an array in a hash, it is auto created.

So your task is as simple as:

```
push ( @{ $uniqueFolders{$key}}, $value) ;
```

Split your file name such that you have a key and value. `File::Spec` and `splitpath` is the right approach.

Reading is as simple as using "keys" on the hash.

e.g.

```
foreach my $path ( keys %uniqueFolders ) {
    print "[KEY]\n";
    print "$path\n"; 
    print "[Values]\n";
    print join ( "\n", @{$uniqueFolders{$path}} ),"\n"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your algorithm,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

local @ARGV = "list_of_files.txt";
my %seen;
for (sort <>) {
  my $d = dirname($_);
  $seen{$d}++ or print qq(\n[KEY]\n$d\n[Values]\n);
  print basename($_);
}
```

output

```
[KEY]
c:\foo\bar
[Values]
aaa.txt
bbb.txt
ccc.txt

[KEY]
d:\xxx
[Values]
ddd.txt
eee.txt
```